# connectivity to mongodb issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have the following code in a script.js file:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    cons = require('consolidate'),
    MongoCl = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    Server = require('mongodb').Server;
app.engine('html', cons.swig);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', __dirname +'/views');

var mongoclient = new MongoCl( new Server('localhost', 27017, {'native_parser' : true}));
var db = mongoclient.db('course');

app.get('/', function (req,res) {
    db.collection('hello_mongo_express').findOne({}, function (err, doc) {
        res.render('hello',doc);
    });
});
app.get('*', function (req,res) {
    res.send('Page not found',404);
});

mongoclient.open(function (err, mongoclient) {
    if(err) throw err;
    var port = 8080;
    app.listen(port);
    console.log("Express server started on port "+port);
});
```

./views/hello.html looks like :

```
<h1>Hello, {{name}}</h1>
```

I have a valid collection within a db 'course'.

When I try running using node, I face the following issue:

```
F:\mongo_proj>node script.js
F:\mongo_proj\script.js:11
var db = mongoclient.db('course');
                     ^

TypeError: mongoclient.db is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\mongo_proj\script.js:11:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:968:3
```

Even though, I guess all the code that creates the mongoclient, db objects, will get called only when the db connectivity is been established. So what could the issue be

edit:
I tried @jerry's suggestion:
[image: output screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

This issue is coming because, you are trying to use mongoclient before it opens connection. So wrap the code in open function as follow:

```
var db;
mongoclient.open(function (err, mongoclient) {
    db = mongoclient.db('course');
    if(err) throw err;
    var port = 8080;
    app.listen(port);
    console.log("Express server started on port "+port);
});
```

See the link for further reference [mongo connection](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/mongoclient.html)

Also this .open() method is used in older versions. With newer version use .connect() method instead. For later versions may be refer this [node driver manual](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/)

Comment: If i move it like that I get the error on the open method of the mongoclient object

Comment: same error? Can you make sure mongo server is running? Also can you monitor the log on starting your server

Comment: This .open() is used with older version of mongodb. From the screen shot I think, you are using 3.2.8 version. With newer versions use .connect() instead

Answer (score 0):

try this.. this simple way of connection

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
  , assert = require('assert');

// Connection URL 
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myproject';
// Use connect method to connect to the Server 
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("Connected correctly to server");

  db.close();
});
```

refer this link and try this

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb